# Further understanding of array.map

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-map

I'm currently learning JS and I'm not quite sure what this does. Could I please get some explanation?

```
  num = num.map(x => {
        return (x == 0) ? 1: 0; 
    }).join("");
```

Thank you.

Comment: Which part presents a problem?

Comment: it's important to read [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: You could invest some more time of checking the official mdn docs. What does Array.map produces as output and what is the purpose of Array.map, rather than asking the same directly on stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

> map calls a provided callbackFn function once for each element in an array, in order, and constructs a new array from the results. callbackFn is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values (including undefined).

```js
// Arrow function
map((element) => { ... })
map((element, index) => { ... })
map((element, index, array) => { ... })

// Callback function
map(callbackFn)
map(callbackFn, thisArg)

// Inline callback function
map(function(element) { ... })
map(function(element, index) { ... })
map(function(element, index, array){ ... })
map(function(element, index, array) { ... }, thisArg)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

So with that in mind, let's take a look at the JS code

```js
  num = num.map(x => {
        return (x == 0) ? 1: 0; 
    }).join("");
```

For me this code is somewhat incomplete, but I would imagine that you might have something like

```js
let num = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

num = num.map(x => {
        return (x == 0) ? 1: 0; 
    }).join("");
// we reassign the value of num to a NEW array, because map will create that for us.
// when we call .map() on our array, it will begin to iterate over the array
// we're giving each element an arbitrary name of 'x'
// In our return statement, we are going to make a comparison with a ternary operator.
// We are going to loosely compare each element of the array (x) to zero.
// If this is true, we reassign x to 1. If this is false, we reassign to 0
// We then join the array with no separators using Array.prototype.join()
// => '0000000000'
```

So now if we do it with another array, let's see what happens.

```js
let num = [0,0,1,1,4,0,5]
num = num.map(x => {
        return (x == 0) ? 1: 0; 
    }).join("");
// => '1100010'
```

Comment: The part of join explanation *"...and in quotes."* is not accurate

Comment: Fixed that, is it more accurate? I forgot that it just means "no separators," thanks for the catch!

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I was really confused with the return part but now I fully understand the concept.

Comment: Glad it helped! Ternary operators can be tricky when starting out, but pretty valuable to know (and more importantly knowing when to use them). :)